# Combining effects using GLFX.js

Tags: javascript, image-processing, frameworks

I have been playing around with GLFX.js and have been able to setup some effects.  What I am missing however is the capability to use each effect together in a sort of layering/blending.  Currently if I increase the slider for say Sepia, and then increase the value for Saturation, Sepia will reset.  I have an inclination that I somehow need to save the current value of the effect on the image each time the slider is updated but not sure how to go about doing that.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you in advance!  Here is my Javascript code:
`

```
window.onload = function() {
  // try to create a WebGL canvas (will fail if WebGL isn't supported)
  try {
    var canvas = fx.canvas();
  } catch (e) {
    alert(e);
    return;
  }

  // convert the image to a texture
  var image = document.getElementById("image");
  var texture = canvas.texture(image);

  let sepiaSlider, sepiaFilter, hueSatFltr, hueSldr, satSldr;

  canvas.draw(texture).update();

  sepiaSlider = document.getElementById("sepia-slider");

  hueSldr = document.getElementById("hue-slider");

  satSldr = document.getElementById("sat-slider");

  hueSldr.addEventListener("input", function(hueVal) {
    hueVal = this.value;
    console.log(hueVal);
    canvas.draw(texture).hueSaturation(hueVal, 0).update();
  });

  satSldr.addEventListener("input", function(satVal) {
    satVal = this.value;
    canvas
      .draw(texture)
      .hueSaturation(0, satVal)
      .update();
  });

  sepiaSlider.addEventListener("input", function(sepiaValue) {
    sepiaValue = this.value;
    console.log(sepiaValue);
    canvas
      .draw(texture)
      .sepia(sepiaValue)
      .update();
  });

  // replace the image with the canvas
  image.parentNode.insertBefore(canvas, image);
  image.parentNode.removeChild(image);
};
```

`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was talking to a colleague, and he was able to help me out with a more direct solution.  For anyone who is interested, it involves using classes.  Here is the cleaned up javascript solution:

```
 /*jshint esversion: 6 */

//set the intial value of canvas so it can be used throughout the program
let canvas = null;

//create a class to hold the intial values
class CurrentSettings {
  constructor(canvas, texture) {
    this.canvas = canvas;
    this.texture = texture;
    this.hue = 0;
    this.sat = 0;
    this.sepia = 0;
    this.brtness = 0;
    this.cntrst = 0;
    this.vgnteSize = 0;
    this.vgnteAmnt = 0;
    this.vbrnce = 0;
  }

  //set the initial values of each effect
  setHue(fValue) {
    this.hue = fValue;
    this.update();
  }

  setSaturation(fValue) {
    this.sat = fValue;
    this.update();
  }

  setSepia(fValue) {
    this.sepia = fValue;
    this.update();
  }

  setBrightness(fValue) {
    this.brtness = fValue;
    this.update();
  }

  setContrast(fValue) {
    this.cntrst = fValue;
    this.update();
  }

  setVignetteSize(fValue) {
    this.vgnteSize = fValue;
    this.update();
  }

  setVignetteAmt(fValue) {
    this.vgnteAmnt = fValue;
    this.update();
  }

  setVibrance(fValue) {
    this.vbrnce = fValue;
    this.update();
  }

  //update the values if the slider is modified
  update() {
    this.canvas.draw(this.texture);
    if (this.hue > 0 || this.sat > 0)
      this.canvas.hueSaturation(this.hue, this.sat);
    if (this.sepia > 0) this.canvas.sepia(this.sepia);

    if (this.brtness > 0 || this.cntrst > 0)
      this.canvas.brightnessContrast(this.brtness, this.cntrst);
    if (this.vgnteSize > 0 || this.vgnteAmnt > 0)
      this.canvas.vignette(this.vgnteSize, this.vgnteAmnt);
    if (this.vbrnce > -1.1) this.canvas.vibrance(this.vbrnce);
    this.canvas.update();
  }
}

//set the initial value of the settings
let pSettings = null;

//if the browser does not support webgl, return an error message
window.onload = function() {
  try {
    canvas = fx.canvas();
  } catch (e) {
    alert(e);
    return;
  }

  //gets the image from the dom
  var image = document.getElementById("image");
  //convets the image from static dom to canvas
  var texture = canvas.texture(image);

  pSettings = new CurrentSettings(canvas, texture);

  //create the variables that will hold the event listeners
  let sepiaSlider,
    hueSldr,
    satSldr,
    brtnessSldr,
    cntrstSldr,
    vgnteSizeSldr,
    vgnteAmtSldr,
    vbrnceSldr;

  //draw the image onto the canvas
  canvas.draw(texture);

  //get all of the slider values
  sepiaSlider = document.getElementById("sepia-slider");

  hueSldr = document.getElementById("hue-slider");

  satSldr = document.getElementById("sat-slider");

  brtnessSldr = document.getElementById("brt-slider");

  cntrstSldr = document.getElementById("ctrs-slider");

  vgnteSizeSldr = document.getElementById("size-vgntte-slider");

  vgnteAmtSldr = document.getElementById("amnt-vgntte-slider");

  vbrnceSldr = document.getElementById("vbrnce-slider");

  //add an event listener to the sliders
  hueSldr.addEventListener("input", function(hueVal) {
    pSettings.setHue(this.value);
  });

  satSldr.addEventListener("input", function(satVal) {
    pSettings.setSaturation(this.value);
  });

  sepiaSlider.addEventListener("input", function(sepiaValue) {
    pSettings.setSepia(this.value);
  });

  brtnessSldr.addEventListener("input", function(brtnessValue) {
    pSettings.setBrightness(this.value);
  });

  cntrstSldr.addEventListener("input", function(cntrstValue) {
    pSettings.setContrast(this.value);
  });

  vgnteSizeSldr.addEventListener("input", function(vgnteSizeValue) {
    pSettings.setVignetteSize(this.value);
  });

  vgnteAmtSldr.addEventListener("input", function(vgnteAmtValue) {
    pSettings.setVignetteAmt(this.value);
  });

  vbrnceSldr.addEventListener("input", function(vbrnceSldrValue) {
    pSettings.setVibrance(this.value);
  });

  canvas.update();

  image.parentNode.insertBefore(canvas, image);
  image.parentNode.removeChild(image);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

As you probably know I can't post a runnable snippet because of cross origin security restrictions, hence I only post my source code. It works and I'm able to apply "ink" and "sepia" effects together. Notice that there is only one call to `draw` and `update` for all effects. Check by yourself and tell me whether it is helpful or not.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>glfx</title>
    <script src="glfx.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <label><input name="ink" type="checkbox" value="ink"> Ink</label>
      <label><input name="sepia" type="checkbox" value="sepia"> Sepia</label>
      <input type="submit">
    </form>
    <img id="image" src="image.png">
    <script>
      var 
        form,
        canvas,
        image,
        texture
      ;
      onload = function () {
        canvas = fx.canvas();
        form = document.forms[0];
        image = document.getElementById("image");
        texture = canvas.texture(image);
        form.addEventListener("submit", onSubmit);
      };
      function onSubmit (ev) {
        var draw = canvas.draw(texture);
        ev.preventDefault();
        if (form.elements.ink.checked) {
          draw = draw.ink(0.25);
        }
        if (form.elements.sepia.checked) {
          draw = draw.sepia(0.75);
        }
        draw.update();
        image.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

To make it run you need an HTTP server. Instructions for Ubuntu :

```
$ cd /tmp
$ wget "https://i.stack.imgur.com/VqFm1.jpg?s=328&g=1" -O image.png
$ wget http://evanw.github.io/glfx.js/glfx.js
$ head -6 demo.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>glfx</title>
    <script src="glfx.js"></script>
$ python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

Finally, open you web browser and type "localhost:8000/demo.html".

Don't forget to press "Submit" :-)

Comment: So it is helpful knowing that I only need one draw and update for all effects.  However I am not able to get this to run.  I press the checkmarks click submit and nothing happens.

Comment: @JoeBates I've added instructions to run it on Ubuntu.